# add cert to com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer

Tags: java, swing, ssl

I'm in a development process of an application in PHP (codeigniter), Jquery. For multiple reasons I had to deploy a Java desktop application in the client desktop and I get the response through $.get function of Jquery. In the test environment I don't have any problem with the package `com.sun.net.httpserver` can I mount a "little" server and can i get that I need. The problem becomes when in the production environment try to access to the server mounted in Java desktop app. The browser block the communication between both for security reasons. I create a subdomain that points to 127.0.0.1 and I create a SSL certificate that I probe in 3 PC's:

1. Fedora with Apache,
2. Windows 7 XAMPP (Apache),
3. Windows 2008 server R2 with IIS 7.5.

In three PC I don't have problem, but when I convert the crt and key file into PKCS cert (*.p12) and then migrate to .jks i can't make a secure connection.

I can't post domains, certificate or another information, only I can post pieces of codes.

[image: Fedora Desktop Installation]
[image: Java Desktop app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same page that give me the original certificate, can merge the cert and the key file in a p12 file then I only convert this p12 file into jks with the command line

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore localhost.jks -srckeystore joined_cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

the certification page that I use for thats is https://startssl.com if someone want generate a proper SSL certificate